# LWUIT support in BlackBerry 10?

Tags: lwuit, blackberry-10

I try to work with BlackBerry 10. I develop on LWUIT. 
I cannot add my LWUIT project to BlackBerry 10.

Do anyone know with which jde this device work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BlackBerry 10 is a totally new platform, which does not use Java-ME.  The old BlackBerry legacy BlackBerry platform is indeed Java-ME.  LWUIT is intended for Java-ME environments, so will not work with BlackBerry-10.

If you know you want to use Java, then you should look at the Android runtime for BlackBerry 10.  However, you will produce a better BlackBerry-10 app if you look at the native API, which isn't Java at all.  It uses C++ and Javascript to put together the UI.  Search for BlackBerry Cascades if you want to target native BlackBerry-10 development.

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier to migrate your code to [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) which supports Android (and iPhone) so it will allow you to convert that to a Blackberry 10 application as well. Codename One is pretty similar to LWUIT (its based on the same code) so should be pretty easy.